# How to send the entire iMessage conversation to a friend? App to take a screenshot of the whole conversation?

Tags: applications, messages, sms

Is there an app for that? I want to send the entire iMessage conversation to a friend, organized, so he can understand the conversation. Not just the text in there. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What OS are you running iMessage? OS X or iOS?

Answer (score 1):

There is likely a log of all your chat history in Library->Messages. If you open the .ichat file in iMessage then it will come up in the standard chat format.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy and paste from Messages, it is organized by who typed each message.